# When to use different types of fuses

Tags: fuses, fuse-holders

Fuses come in all sorts of shapes and sizes, assuming that i have a specification for its current and how fast i need it, what are the other considerations for choosing a fuse type?

Fuse types that i know of:

1. Blade automotive fuses
2. Ceramic SMD fuses
3. Radial glass fuses with holders
4. Fusible links

Comment: Voltage rating and breaking capacity come to mind as considerations.

Comment: physical connections, reliability/quality. explosion proof  plastic, ceramic vs glass. or not to fuse with other methods maintenance free, lightning risks

Comment: do you mean `axial glass fuses`?

Comment: I think theg refer to the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I don't enjoy a good E-Geek conversation, but this type of question is best and most easily answered by just seeking out the true experts.

[https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electrical/application-notes/powr-gard-technical-application-guide.pdf](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electrical/application-notes/powr-gard-technical-application-guide.pdf)

Like so many other things in EE, there's alot more going on than meets the eye at first glance.  Fuses aren't just a wire in a tube, they're a result of literally 100 years of learning & improving.

Comment: I am asking about the scale of hobby projects so like max 100A not true experts level.

Comment: LOL      Well 100A isn't exactly "chicken feed"   ;)        You don't necessarily need to read that WHOLE application note, but there's certainly enough readable material to answer your question.   Another option is seek out the information on WIkipedia.     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical)    I know alot of people slag on Wikipedia as being 'inaccurate" because it's open-source and anybody can edit it ... Maybe it is wonky for topics like politicians and rock bands, but when I look up something "technical", it's always spot on. Geeks must not be interested in corrupting truths!

Comment: I meen what fuse options are available for hobbists

Comment: Ahhhh....   Well you can get ANYTHING nowadays - Internet makes that easy.    Probably most common type of fuse and fuse holder is the 5x20mm cartridge fuse.   And if you're going 100A for real, use "ceramic" not glass as they're better at not exploding.   Although I don't know if 100A fuses exist in this size.   Just look in DIgikey or Mouser, you can buy anything you want for low money.